# C++ program works in Visual Studio Debugger but shuts down halfway through when ran through the exe

Tags: c++

I have written a simple Euclidean algorithm as an assignment in C++ using Visual Studio and it works without any problems when I run it in the IDE itself, however when I try running it with the generated exe it shuts down halfway through after asking the user for their input.

```cpp
int main(void)
{

    //Variablendeklaration

    int n;
    int r;
    int m;
    int erg;
    int temp;
    int temp2;

    //Zahlenabfrage
    
    printf("Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl fuer m.\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &m);
    printf("Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl fuer n.\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    
    temp = m;
    temp2 = n;

    //Algorithmus, um den großten gemeinsamen Teiler zwischen zwei vom Benutzer eingegebenen //Zahlen herauszufinden

    while (n > 0) {
        r = m % n;
        m = n;
        n = r;
        erg = m;

    }
    
    //Das Ergebnis wird auf dem Bildschirm angezeigt

    printf("Der groesster gemeinsamer Teiler von %d und %d betraegt %d",temp,temp2,erg);
    
    //Programm anhalten, damit der Benutzer genügend Zeit hat, sich das Ergebnis anzuschauen
    
    getchar();
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the program and I believe it breaks after the line temp2 = n;
I would appreciate if you could dumb down the potential explanations as I am a beginner.

added getchar();
the program should at the end tell me the biggest divider between two numbers given by the user at the start but it breaks down after the user gives the numbers.

Comment: declaring all variables upfront makes the code harder to read because one has to jump back and forth to understand it. Better declare variables only when you need them

Comment: Will keep that in mind thank you, this is the way our professors teach us which I find a bit odd as well.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. Details matter. Also include the input that makes the program halt

Comment: we cannot reporoduce the error unless you provide more details, e.g. the definition of `getChar()`, and how you run the code.

Comment: define "shuts down halfway" ? Does it print anything?

Comment: Sample input/output would be helpful. Code runs fine here, e.g. `"Der groesster gemeinsamer Teiler von 5132 und 10 betraegt 2"`. (it is)  Side notes, which can largely be cured by enabling warnings, and not accepting code until it compiles without warning. (`/W3` for visual studio, e.g. `cl.exe` compiler is fine). You cannot use ANY input function correctly unless you ***check the return***, e.g. `if (scanf_s ("%d", &m) != 1) { /* handle error */ }`. Always provide a newline as the final output from your program to make your program POSIX compliant.